# C++ get default value of class member without creating new object

Tags: c++, c++11, default-value, static-members

Let's consider definition:

```
struct ClassWithMember
{
    int myIntMember = 10;
}
```

I'd like **to get `myIntMember`'s default value**, but do not create another instance of the class

```
// IMPOSSIBLE int myInt = ClassWithMember::myIntMember;  
// MUST AVOID int myInt = ClassWithMember().myIntMember;
```

---

I know workaround, but dislike it:

```
struct ClassWithMember
{
    static const int myIntMember_DEFAULT = 10;
    int myIntMember = myIntMember_DEFAULT;
}
int myInt = ClassWithMember::myIntMember_DEFAULT;
```

Because it needs extra line. And I cannot define inline static pointers like `static const int *const INTEGER11_DEFAULT = 0x100088855;`, such pointers must be defined in `.cpp` file, in `.hpp` is only declaration. Many of my classes are header-only, so create excess `.cpp` for this value isn't good idea.

**[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990066/get-default-value-of-class-member)** is the similar question for C#

Comment: "I know workaround, but dislike it" .... may be you should explain why ??

Comment: Because it needs one more line. And I cannot define inline static pointers like `static const int *const INTEGER11 = 11;`, pointers must be defined in `.cpp` file, in `.hpp` only declaration.

Comment: "static const int *const INTEGER11 = 11" is not valid statement, and this is not the same as the question above that is all about accessibility... please edit your question to match your real concern.

Comment: real concern is **get default value of class member without creating new object**. Pointer or not does not meter.

Comment: "is not valid statement" - Yes. And that is problem, but is secondary.

Comment: I think this is an interesting question. In-class member initializers were made as a kind of shortcut to writing the same initialization list for constructors, so we all thought of the "default" values as existing in that fashion; unattainable (unless set through some other global). Looking at it them in this light, though, one is quite justified in asking "Why? The value is right there!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I call this solution *workaround*

```
struct ClassWithMember
{
    static const int myIntMember_DEFAULT = 10;
    int myIntMember = myIntMember_DEFAULT;
}
int myInt = ClassWithMember::myIntMember_DEFAULT;
```

For pointers it will look more complicated

```
//.hpp
struct ClassWithMember
{
    static AnotherClass* const myMember_DEFAULT;  //=X; Assignment not allowed
    AnotherClass* myMember = myMember_DEFAULT;
}
//.cpp
AnotherClass* const MyNamespace::ClassWithMember::myMember_DEFAULT = pAnotherInstance;
//usage
auto *my = ClassWithMember::myMember_DEFAULT;
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that, for you, is only another workaround but I think is a little (only a little) more practical.

If you save the default value as a static const that is returned by a static method, you can avoid the additional line in the cpp file.

The following example do the trick in a template wrapper (with default value as template parameter with a default vaule; just for fun) but the template part is just to avoid the duplication of code in the example

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, T defTpl = T{}>
struct wrapperWithDef
 {
   static T getDefVal ()
    { static T const def { defTpl }; return def; }

   T myTMember { getDefVal() };
 };

int main()
 {
   wrapperWithDef<int>          wi;
   wrapperWithDef<long, 3L>     wl;
   wrapperWithDef<int *>        wp;

   // print "0, 3, (nil)" (clang++) or "0, 3, 0" (g++)
   std::cout << wi.myTMember << ", " << wl.myTMember << ", "
      << wp.myTMember << std::endl;

   // print "5, (nil), 1" (clang++) or "5, 0, 1" (g++)
   std::cout << wrapperWithDef<unsigned, 5U>::getDefVal() << ", "
      << wrapperWithDef<long *>::getDefVal() << ", "
      << wrapperWithDef<bool, true>::getDefVal() << std::endl;

   return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a thought to consider if you can afford having `constexpr`-friendly structs. `consteval` can be used to force the object's initialization (and destruction) at compilation time.
This example shows a way to have a default value for `std::string` via `std::string_view` (since C++20): https://godbolt.org/z/jxh1s8qev

```
#include <type_traits>

#include <array>
#include <string>

template <typename T, typename V>
consteval V _mem_type(V T::*) noexcept;

template <auto M, typename = decltype(_mem_type(M))>
struct default_value;

template <typename T, typename V, V T::*M>
struct default_value<M, std::enable_if_t<std::is_fundamental_v<V>, V>>
{
    consteval V operator()() const {
        return T{}.*M;
    }
};

// This is only possible starting from C++20
template <typename T, std::string T::*M>
struct default_value<M, std::string>
{
private:
    constexpr static auto _v = 
        []
        {
            std::array<char, (T{}.*M).size()> v{};
            auto i = v.begin();
            for (char c: T{}.*M)
                *i++ = c;
            
            return v;
        }();

public:
    consteval std::string_view operator()() const {
        return {&_v[0], _v.size()};
    }
};

template <auto M>
constexpr inline default_value<M> default_value_v{};

// Example
//////////

#include <iostream>

struct foo
{
    int i = 815;
    std::string s = "oceanic";
};

int main() {
    constexpr int iDefault = default_value_v<&foo::i>();
    std::cout << "default foo::i = " << iDefault << '\n';

    constexpr auto sDefault = default_value_v<&foo::s>();
    std::cout << "default foo::s = " << sDefault << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
default foo::i = 815
default foo::s = oceanic
```

Basically one have to workaround the returning of the contents for types that use dynamic allocations.

Obviously, it is not going to work with types that are non `constexpr` friendly, because it is not allowed to return dynamically-allocated resources from a constexpr context.